# Can the @Subscribe annotation in guava be wrapped?

Tags: java, guava

I am using Google's Guava EventBus in one of my projects and am wondering if there is a way to wrap the @Subscribe annotation so that rather than importing the guava event bus  package I can just rely on another class within my working package.

I found this on the net which seems to be the same thing I am looking for.  Was wondering if anyone could give a second opinion.

> If a class needs to subscribe to a message it has to have some of its
>   methods annotated with the Subscribe annotation. I can wrap up the
>   EventBus in my own custom wrapper, but that doesn’t fix the Subscribe
>   annotation issue. I’d like something that has less coupling throughout
>   my code.
>
> http://www.lexicalscope.com/blog/2012/02/13/guava-eventbus-experiences/

Comment: If you're using the Guava `EventBus`, then what's the problem with adding another import to that same package?  It doesn't incur any added overhead.

Comment: Also, what does this have to do with Guice instead of Guava?

Comment: Yea both good points made the edits.. @Louis That is my understanding of it, but it is strange that there would be no other way....

Comment: @LouisWasserman The problem with adding another import to the same package, is that you will not be adding it in the same place. To use the EventBus itself you only have to add _one_ import in the top-level class where you set up the event bus. To use the subscribe annotation you have to add one import in _every_ class that wants to subscribe to a message. Which is an irritation if you use those same classes in another non-eventbus context, and an outright problem if those classes are in an external library. (disclaimer, my article is being quoted in the question)